# Should the British be getting ready for a no-deal Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

As an American, I have been watching the Brexit proceedings with some confusion. To all appearances, British politicians do not want to compromise, and the European leaders do not want to compromise. This suggests that a no-deal Brexit will occur on the 12th of April (Friday). Given the dire warnings about the dangers of a no-deal Brexit, I would have expected people to be taking precautions, such as stockpiling food or medicine. Why is that not happening? Are the deleterious effects of a no-deal Brexit longer term rather than shorter term? Or is everyone assuming that some kind of deal will be struck at the last minute?

Comment: My impression has been that no-deal Brexit will have effects more like the 2008 USA recession than the USA Great Depression. It certainly won't be as bad as, for example, Venezuela's collapse.

Comment: FWIW May is cognizant that the UK's union might be at stake in the event of a no deal Brexit. IMHO the only sensible scenario where no deal might occur at this point is by accident. It would be after the EU rejects an extension for some reason or another (it could very well be this one, but I'd gather May will get a long extension) and, with a gun to their faces, the MPs fail to subsequently accept a variation of May's deal and then fail to repeal article 50.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Hasn't may ruled out repealing A50 already? At this point no deal brexit seems inevitable if may fails to secure an extension.

Comment: The UK has agreed to hold European elections. I think that significantly reduces the chances of leaving. I think we're at the point where the situation is "critical, but not serious"

Comment: Tactically, yes. The UK "should" have been actively preparing for no-deal more than 2 years ago. With adequate preparation, the government could therefore show the EU that they were ready and had nothing to fear - and therefore would have had a much stronger negotiating position. History will surely make case studies of the blunders of negotiation which have occurred over the past 2 years.

Comment: @ChrisMelville of course, that would have forced a lot of the business no deal planning to occur earlier. Since in many cases this is "close UK arm of the business" that would have made it clear much earlier that the game was up.

Comment: @Magisch: So? She also ruled out holding snap elections after coming to power, agreeing to a backstop, etc. It's not like she'll have a choice, too. When MPs will be on the cliff edge, with no further extension possible, and asked to vote on her deal one last time, they could reject it. Or Bercow could simply disallow another vote on it. What next if that happens? Fearing no deal, MPs will likely demand a vote on revoking article 50, with no deal guaranteed if they don't vote aye. And if that vote occurs, methinks it's Brexit end-game.

Comment: No politician is allowed to say that the *real* negotiations will start the day *after* a theoretical "no deal" has happened. But that's the political reality of the situation.

Comment: @pjc50 " I think that significantly reduces the chances of leaving." What political signal would it send to Europe (and to Westminster) if a large proportion of the UK's newly elected MEPs were members of UKIP? Not that many people in the UK think the European parliament is anything except an expenses gravy-train for its members, but even so...

Comment: Mrs May is asking the EU for another extension today. It's looking a lot like it'll be extended until some arrangement can be reached.

Comment: @alephzero well, the largest proportion (24 seats!) were UKIP in the 2014 European elections. Perhaps that contributed to us being in this situation in the first place.

Comment: @alephzero "real negotiations" .. on exactly the same set of blocking problems? NI, citizens residence, customs? Except with the UK in logistics chaos?

Comment: @ChrisMelville The UK *has* been actively preparing for no-deal for the past two years. Lots of critical agreements and acts have already been prepared (and ratified), and there's guidance published by the HMR&C. Don't assume there was no preparation just because newspapers don't write about it. Media get lots of attention for making crises seem bigger than they really are; there's little benefit to saying "Don't worry, this isn't something that was just left to rot for two years while everybody prays for a divine intervention".

Comment: @Luaan could we have a list of ratified agreements please?

Comment: I think there is a big difference between the preparations that have been made by businesses and those made by individuals.  Most individuals wouldn't seriously consider stockpiling food, beyond a few extra tins of beans, that's just not the British way.  We can live without French wine and German sausages for a few weeks until it's all sorted and everyone has shaken hands and restored things to their proper order.

Comment: @pjc50 A list? Probably not. I doubt it's filed somewhere under "no deal contingency" - they're merely various trade and other agreements between countries. But it does include agreements with Switzerland, IAEA, new aviation agreements with individual countries (including the US and Canada) etc. The new laws deal with things like rebuilding duties, adding the EU laws that the UK wants to keep (like the Nuclear Safeguards Act, European Union Withdrawal Act, ...). You'll find issues that aren't covered yet, but that's a far cry from "there's no preparation!".

Comment: @pjc50 And it's frankly a bit annoying that people discuss this issue without even casually reading through the official documents, like https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-governments-preparations-for-a-no-deal-scenario/uk-governments-preparations-for-a-no-deal-scenario. Again, just because there's plans doesn't mean everything is going to go smoothly or that a no-deal exit is preferable, but *it has been planned for*. There's lots of public guidance and information about what the government is doing to prepare (including minor issues like Erasmus+).

Comment: (And now there is a delay until October 31. That is the kind of thing I expected. Did everyone know?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Given the dire warnings about the dangers of a no-deal Brexit, I would have expected people to be taking precautions, such as stockpiling food

This is happening, from the [FT (February 2019)](https://www.ft.com/content/27ab5752-2604-11e9-b329-c7e6ceb5ffdf):

> But the closely watched purchasing managers’ index compiled by IHS Markit/CIPS on Friday showed concrete evidence that stockpiling was becoming widespread — particularly in the food and drink, clothing, chemical and plastics, and electrical and electronics sectors — and was being implemented at more larger companies than small ones.

> or medicine.

Same here, from the Guardian ([first quote](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/sep/06/government-talks-drug-companies-medicines-stockpiling-brexit), [second quote](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/oct/23/brexit-patients-may-need-own-drug-stockpiles-pharma-execs-tell-commons-committee)):

> The government is in talks with drug companies about funding the extra costs of stockpiling and flying in vital medicines in the event of a no-deal Brexit, the health secretary has revealed.

> Patients should consider stockpiling their own drugs if it looks likely the UK will leave the EU with no deal, the pharmaceuticals industry has said, telling MPs that such a scenario could be “catastrophic” for medicine supplies and necessitate emergency powers.

Why is that not happening? Are the deleterious effects of a no-deal Brexit longer term rather than shorter term?

There are many effects, both in the long term and in the short term. The stockpiling is actually only a band-aid solution, especially with regard to fresh food one can only stockpile for a few weeks (or less), according to [the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-46111085):

> Fresh food - which cannot be stockpiled - is the biggest concern. A vegetable shortage last year, driven by bad weather in southern Europe, highlighted this dependence, and led to a flurry of pictures on social media of empty supermarket shelves.

The thing with most food (and [other importers, like manufacturing plants](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/sep/29/no-deal-brexit-could-halt-production-at-uk-toyota-plants)) coming into the UK is that it works with so-called just-in-time deliveries, from [the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-46111085):

> The UK's supply chains work on a "just in time" basis, meaning stock is delivered daily, not stored for long periods in warehouses.
>
> [...]
>
> To illustrate the complexity, Paul Martin, UK head of retail at consultancy KPMG, says 290 trucks come through Dover each day just supplying citrus fruits. He says any level of disruption, such as trucks needing to pass extra inspections, is likely to have an impact.

One of the 'problems' here is that UK imports rely heavily on the Dutch Port of Rotterdam. Indeed, many imports to the UK from Asia go via Rotterdam. Or to quote Mark Dijk, the Port's external affairs manager (as cited by [the Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/brexit-ports-customs-union-u-turn-rotterdam-eu-trade-single-market-theresa-may-david-davis-a8303436.html)):

> “We are also a hub for the UK. All the deep-sea ships from China are coming into Rotterdam, and their goods are then going into shallow water ships to the UK,”
>
> Or is everyone assuming that some kind of deal will be struck at the last minute?

No, as pointed out by Fizz, there are no-deal preparations going on on both sides of the Channel. And those preparations have been going on for a while now.

Comment: with the caveat that stockpiling you mention/quote is being conducted by business and/or the government.

Comment: @Fizz that's right, there are also examples of civilians stockpiling food and medicine, but I think the businesses provide a better example as they're making business decisions, civilian 'hoarders' are [found everywhere](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2069270/) and it's not easy to show their decisions always have merit or that they're just overreacting.

Answer (score 4):

The UK government has put out no-deal Brexit [info for businesses](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/partnership-pack-preparing-for-a-no-deal-eu-exit/how-this-pack-will-help-you-prepare-for-a-no-deal-scenario). (And so has the EU.) But this is presumably not expected to be like a natural disaster, so the general public hasn't been instructed to do anything in particular, insofar, and as far as I know.

For individuals, there are [instructions/information](https://www.gov.uk/prepare-eu-exit) dealing with the new border procedures, EU studies programmes, EU family law, and "buying things from Europe".

The "should" part of your question probably only admits answers that are primarily opinion based, at the moment.

Comment: There's not much for the general public to do, really. Even if you wanted to, say, hoard some extra medical supplies, if everyone does this (at guidance from the government, no less), it will probably raise the prices anyway. All the while raising completely unwarranted panic, making people waste money and time etc. Businesses need to prepare, people don't - they just need to know about the changes that affect them directly (as you mentioned), which mostly means things like "don't forget to get a passport if you're planning a vacation".

Answer (score 2):

The British should certainly be preparing for it, and I think some are, but I would be shocked if the UK actually crashes out with no deal on April 12th. Like everyone else, I'm not entirely sure what is going to happen as things seem to change almost on a daily basis. For example, last week President Macron was signalling that he'd had enough of the UK's indecision and would veto any extension to the leave date. However, almost immediately after that, the Taoiseach of Ireland Leo Varadkar said that whoever pulled such a move would "never be forgiven".

Because of that, I can't see a hard Brexit being precipitated by the EU, because their perceived self strength lies in their unity, which until now has been unshakeable. What's more likely, at least in the short term (Theresa May is asking for an extension to June 30th), is that the proverbial can will continue to be kicked down the road by the British government whilst it remains paralysed by indecision and division.

A hard Brexit can only happen now if a British government allows it to happen. There are still plenty of politicians and people in the country who want that.

Comment: I have personally not prepared for it, and I see it as a very unlikely event. I think talking about a no-deal exit is politicians bluffing to try and get their way, but it's not going to happen. On April 12, most likely the can will be kicked, less likely article 50 will be revoked, even less likely a no-deal exit will occur.

Comment: It certainly looks that way. We could be still talking about this next year.

Answer (score 1):

The government is between a rock and a hard place.

Full scale preparations would cost a huge amount of money, and cause the public to start panicking. Imagine if the government told supermarkets to stockpile long life foods, people would go crazy buying up supplies.

Some years ago there was a problem with the supply of petrol with a similar reaction. People queuing for hours to put a few litres of fuel in their cars out of fear. People stockpiling and [taking advantage with high prices](https://www.rte.ie/news/business/2019/0122/1024795-brexit-survival-kit/).

On the other hand, if the UK does crash out of the EU it's going to need those stockpiles. The government has been trying to put contingency plans in place, but it's not been going well.

So the UK government is strongly motivated to keep its preparations low key and largely secret (e.g. [possible medicine shortages](https://youtu.be/kqnUpi8dFcc), [having the army on standby](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-46910535)), but also needs to spend billions on them to ensure it doesn't have mass panic, riots and people dying...

All the while saying that no-deal is a real threat as a negotiating position with the EU and with it's own MPs and Parliament, and simultaneously trying to obey its legal obligation to avoid a no-deal crash.

It's as crazy as it sounds.